# issue with my path variable

Tags: linux, centos, path

my path variable seems to be a bit hosed. I recently modified my /etc/profile to add GRAILS_HOME and modify JAVA_HOME. the problem now (moved off of grails to lift for the time being) is that there is an extra `/` in one of the directories. I'm not sure how to find where this is set in or der to fix it. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
echo $PATH
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27:/home/Ramy/grails/bin:/usr/local//bin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27:/home/Ramy/grails/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java
```

UPDATE:

I killed my terminal and opened a new one. the extra `/` seems to be gone. However, when I'm now getting this:

```
[Ramy@localhost ~]$ sbt
Invalid or corrupt jarfile /usr/local/bin
[Ramy@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27:/home/Ramy/grails/bin:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/Ramy/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java/bin
```

Here's the contents of /usr/local/bin/sbt:

```
java -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx2048M -Xss4M -jar `dirname $0` /sbt-launcher.jar "$@"
```

Comment: Am I drunk or is there really anything twice (or more) in your PATH?

Comment: I can't tell you if you're drunk but there originally was a double `/` in the initial echo of $PATH: `:/usr/local//bin:` Restarting the terminal took care of the slash.

Comment: `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java/bin` is there two times in the second $PATH. I doubt that it causes any problems, but it's strange.

Comment: and double slashes should not cause any problems, try this `cd //boot/..///etc//..//dev/` (you should end up in dev) at least bash handles it fine.

Comment: hmmm...weird. well i've deleted and re-downloaded the jar file so I'm not sure it's the jar file that's the problem

Comment: what is this `Invalid or corrupt jarfile /usr/local/bin` all about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i was following along in the book "Lift in Action" and the advice they give for creating the file called "sbt" was inaccurate. It should look like this:

```
java -Xmx512M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

ref: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup